# Using postMessage in Firefox the data object is seemingly overwritten

Tags: javascript, angularjs, firefox, iframe

I'm trying to communicate between an iframe and its parent using postMessage. The code shown below works fine in Chrome and Safari but in Firefox the object is overwritten.

Code on iframe:

```
parent.postMessage(data, '*');
```

Code on parent:

```
$window.addEventListener("message", interpretMessage, false);
```

(that dollar sign there is because I'm using angular.)

console log on chrome or safari shows:

```
{
  "data": {
    "message": "message"
  }
}
```

on firefox it shows:

```
"{
  "isTrusted": false
}"
```

Would anyone be able to advise on a fix/workaround?

Answer (score 0):

Having done some further testing it appears this is an issue with Angular rather than with Firefox. To post messages between frames when at least one frame is Angular use this solution: https://github.com/kylewelsby/angular-post-message

Comment: Do you know why exactly it works in other browsers but not Firefox? Sounds strange that a framework should introduce such a gotcha..